# Python learner -- trouble creating a class

Tags: python, class

I cannot figure out why this simple Python code to create a class called Resto will not run. The traceback says the name "Resto" is not defined (at the end of the code where I am making an instance of the class). But I successfully created other classes by following this exact format.

```
class Resto:
    """ a model of a restaurant """
    def __init__(self, name, cuisine):
        """ attributes of the restaurant """
        self.name = name
        self.cuisine = cuisine

    def describe_resto(self):
        print (f"{self.name} features {self.cuisine} cooking.")

    def resto_open(self):
        print (f"{self.name} is open Tuesday through Sunday, from 6 to midnight.")

    Alices = Resto ("Alice's", "Canadian")
    Alices.describe_resto()
    Alices.resto_open()
```

Comment: The last three lines are currently part of the class `Resto`. They shouldn't be. Outdent them to line up with `class`.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is because `Alices = Resto (...)` line and the lines after that line is indented on the same level as the stuff inside `Resto`.
Try removing their indentation (make them align to the left with no spaces).

Comment: Yes, it's trying to execute those lines during the definition of the class, and the class doesn't yet exist at that point.

Comment: Thanks so much. I stared at this code for a long time!!

Answer (score 1):

You must instantiate the class outside of the class itself, because at the time of execution, the class doesn't yet exist. It is trying to execute the lines to create an instance of the class, inside of the uninstantiated class itself. So un-indent the last 3 lines:

```
class Resto:
    """ a model of a restaurant """
    def __init__(self, name, cuisine):
        """ attributes of the restaurant """
        self.name = name
        self.cuisine = cuisine

    def describe_resto(self):
        print (f"{self.name} features {self.cuisine} cooking.")

    def resto_open(self):
        print (f"{self.name} is open Tuesday through Sunday, from 6 to midnight.")

Alices = Resto ("Alice's", "Canadian")
Alices.describe_resto()
Alices.resto_open()
```

Output:

```
Alice's features Canadian cooking.
Alice's is open Tuesday through Sunday, from 6 to midnight.
```